# Why can't you use scanf() in C for multiple input arguments of different types?

Tags: c, scanf

Why is this considered illegal in C ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int integer;
    char character;
    float floatingPoint;

    scanf(" %d %c %f", integer, character, floatingPoint);

    return 0;
}
```

The above code produces the following error message under `cc` compiler.

```
cc Chapter2ex1.c
Chapter2ex1.c: In function ‘main’:
Chapter2ex1.c:8:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type   ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
 scanf(" %d%c%f", integer, character, floatingPoint);
 ^
Chapter2ex1.c:8:5: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
Chapter2ex1.c:8:5: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 4 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
```

Comment: 'Cause you forgot the `&`?

Comment: To the person that down voted my question, can you please explain your reason for doing so ? I'm learning and I made a mistake, that's all.

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm: I'm not the downvoter, but some people are a bit  trigger-happy with the downvote button. My guess is that they didn't like the fact that it's a question about a simple typo. I hope it doesn't deter you from asking questions in the future, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write

```
 //                 v---------v-----------v-- addresses taken here
 scanf(" %d %c %f", &integer, &character, &floatingPoint);
```

`scanf` needs to know the places where it should write the values it reads, not the values that currently reside there.